# Large file downloads don't work in Firefox browser

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a Angular app where users can download some documents(.jpg, .mp4 and .pdf) that they uploaded. Basically the download of the file works in this way: A service is called which returns some information about the file as name, type, size and the content of it in base64.

This is the download method in Component when the user clicks on the download button:

```js
downloadDocument(doc: Document) {
  this._subDownDocument = this.service.getDocument(doc).subscribe((resp: Document) => {
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = resp.fileName;
    link.target = "_blank";

    // Construct the URI
    link.href = resp.url;//Url is the content of the file in base64
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();

    // Cleanup the DOM
    document.body.removeChild(link);
  });
}
```

It's working perfectly for files up to 12mb. But when files are bigger the download doesn't start, the service brings the file correctly but I don't know why the download doesn't start. No error is shown in the browser console.

This problem only happens with Firefox because in Google Chrome it works fine. Any idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: What happens when you insert resp.url into url bar in Mozilla?

Comment: I can't do this because it's a huge string and when I check the console it seems that fire fox truncate it.

Comment: But If i try: window.open(resp.url); I got this error: ERROR DOMException: An invalid or illegal string was specified

Comment: Just remove the `appendChild() ` line, you will see the click still works. Here you are populating the DOM with the huge base64 url, it's why it blocks, the DOM is full. And of course you can also remove the removeChild line !

Comment: I did what you suggested but still not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by installing [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js). It's used for large files purposes.

```js
npm install file-saver --save
```

And changed my download method to:

```js
downloadDocument(doc: Document) {
  this._subDownDocument = this.service.getDocument(doc).subscribe((resp: Document) => {

   //Url is the content of the file in base64
   fileSaver.saveAs(this.b64toBlob(resp.url, resp.type), resp.fileName);

  });
}

private b64toBlob(dataURI, type) {

  var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
  var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
  var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);

  for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return new Blob([ab], { type: type });
}
```